# How do I write an LSB init script for a process that already daemonizes properly?

Tags: linux, init-script, daemon

I have a process that already `fork`s into the background, but I can't find any guides anywhere on how to write an init script for a program like this.

Comment: You can use an existing script as a template. I have used existing scripts as templates successfully. There are many examples around. Here is a link I found. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/ I have no association with `thegeekstuff.com`

Comment: @fossil The script starts the daemon, but when running `status` on the script, it says the daemon is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existing script as a template. I have used existing scripts as templates successfully. There are many examples around. Here is a link I found. thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script I have no association with thegeekstuff.com

Usually a script that forks in background will create a file in `/var/run/`. For example, here is the example of `pid` file created by `ssh`

```
ubuntu@fm:/var$ ls /var/run/sshd.pid 
/var/run/sshd.pid
ubuntu@fm:/var$ cat /var/run/sshd.pid 
1117
ubuntu@fm:/var$ ps -C sshd
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  319 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  375 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 1117 ?        00:00:01 sshd
```

When one checks status using `myinitscript status`, the script can check whether this forked PID exists.

Comment: I set a `pid` file but it does not appear.

Comment: @robbie0630 Could you post the portion which checks the status and also the path and content of `pid` file.

Comment: The portion is unchanged from the template, the path is `/var/run/daemonz.pid`, and the content does not exist because the file does not exist. It could be because I'm using crouton on a chromebook, though. (there is also no syslog) I could try testing everything on another computer.

Comment: @robbie0630 the `daemon` may be just creating the file. It has to add the `pid` of `forked` process.